# WordPress Widget Select Box selections not displaying correctly on save

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, widget

I've created a Widget that pulls the titles from a custom post type as options to select.  When I click "Save" on the widget, everything disappears. BUT, if I refresh the widgets page and go back to that widget, everything shows up properly. It's just on that initial "Save" that things look wonky.

As an aside, I'm trying to figure out how to grab the featured image of each item selected in order to display it on the frontend. Having trouble figuring that out. But if I need to post this question separately that's fine.

```
// Product Slider Widget //
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
register_widget( 'DNF_Product_Slider_Widget' );
});

class DNF_Product_Slider_Widget extends WP_Widget {

// Register widget //
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'dnf_product_slider_widget',
        __('DNF Product Slider', 'dnf'),
        array( 'description' => __( 'A widget to display 6 products, 2 at a time, in a slider', 'dnf' ), )
    );
}

// Displays the widget settings controls on the widget panel //
public function form($instance) {

    $defaults = array('title' => __('Product Slider'), 'product1' => '', 'product2' => '', 'product3' => '', 'product4' => '', 'product5' => '', 'product6' => '');
    $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults);

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'dnf_simple_products'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'dnf-cat' );
    $url = $thumb['0'];
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Product 1:</label>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) {?>
        <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('product1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('product1'); ?>" type="text">
            <option label="" disabled></option>
            <optgroup label="Select a Product">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Product 2:</label>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) {?>
        <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('product2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('product2'); ?>" type="text">
            <option label="" disabled></option>
            <optgroup label="Select a Product">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>


    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Product 3:</label>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) {?>
        <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('product3'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('product3'); ?>" type="text">
            <option label="" disabled></option>
            <optgroup label="Select a Product">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Product 4:</label>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) {?>
        <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('product4'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('product4'); ?>" type="text">
            <option label="" disabled></option>
            <optgroup label="Select a Product">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Product 5:</label>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) {?>
        <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('product5'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('product5'); ?>" type="text">
            <option label="" disabled></option>
            <optgroup label="Select a Product">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Product 6:</label>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) {?>
        <select class='widefat' id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('product6'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('product6'); ?>" type="text">
            <option label="" disabled></option>
            <optgroup label="Select a Product">
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <option value='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <?php } ?>
    </p>

    <?php
}

// Save widget selections //
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;

    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['product1'] = $new_instance['product1'];
    $instance['product2'] = $new_instance['product2'];
    $instance['product3'] = $new_instance['product3'];
    $instance['product4'] = $new_instance['product4'];
    $instance['product5'] = $new_instance['product5'];
    $instance['product6'] = $new_instance['product6'];

    return $instance;
}

// Display the widget on the frontend //
public function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args);

    $product1 = $instance['product1'];
    $product2 = $instance['product2'];
    $product3 = $instance['product3'];
    $product4 = $instance['product4'];
    $product5 = $instance['product5'];
    $product6 = $instance['product6'];

    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    $title = $instance['title'];

    echo $before_widget;

    if (trim($title) != '')
        echo '<h6>' . $title . '</h6>';

        echo '<div class="well"><div id="productCarousel" class="carousel slide prods"><div class="carousel-inner">';

    if (!empty($product1))
        echo '<div class="item active"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $url1 . '"><div class="caption"><h3>' . $product1 . '</h3></div></div></div>';
    if (!empty($product2))
        echo '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $url2 . '"><div class="caption"><h3>' . $product2 . '</h3></div></div></div></div></div>';
    if (!empty($product3))
        echo '<div class="item"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $url3 . '"><div class="caption"><h3>' . $product3 . '</h3></div></div></div>';
    if (!empty($product4))
        echo '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $url4 . '"><div class="caption"><h3>' . $product4 . '</h3></div></div></div></div></div>';
    if (!empty($product5))
        echo '<div class="item"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $url5 . '"><div class="caption"><h3>' . $product5 . '</h3></div></div></div>';
    if (!empty($product6))
        echo '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $url6 . '"><div class="caption"><h3>' . $product6 . '</h3></div></div></div></div></div>';

        echo '</div>';
        echo '<a class="left carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></a>';
        echo '<a class="right carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a>';
        echo '</div></div>';
    echo $after_widget;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>` instead?

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the post. I'm not having difficulty pulling in the names of the posts. I'm having trouble with the choices made disappearing upon hitting save. Then I refresh the widgets page, return to that widget, and everything appears correct. So it's actually saving the selections, it just doesn't look like it when you first hit "save". I need *that* fixed.